# None vs nil in Elixir

Tags: elixir

What is the difference between `None` and `nil` in Elixir?

From Elixir's documentation if I understand correctly `nil` is a literal representing absence of value.

But even `None` seems to represent the same, though I could not find any documentation over it.

Comment: There is no None in Elixir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JustMichael mentioned, `None` behaves nothing like you think.
`None` in elixir is just an atom without any further meaning, as you can determine via `i(variable)` in iex.

```
iex(1)> i(None)
Term
  None
Data type
  Atom
Raw representation
  :"Elixir.None"
Reference modules
  Atom
Implemented protocols
  IEx.Info, Inspect, String.Chars, List.Chars
iex(2)> is_nil(None)
false
```

But looking at `nil`:

```
iex(3)> i(nil)
Term
  nil
Data type
  Atom
Reference modules
  Atom
Implemented protocols
  IEx.Info, Inspect, String.Chars, List.Chars
iex(4)> is_nil(nil)
true
```

Answer (score 0):

`None` is a module name, an atom, that doesn't evaluate to false in control flow.
`nil` is an atom that evaluates to false in control flow.

```
iex(1)> if None, do: :ok, else: :ko
:ok
iex(2)> if nil, do: :ok, else: :ko
:ko
```

Comment: `None` by itself is not a module name. It is just like any other atom. It has no special meaning. However, because it starts with an uppercase letter, it gets expanded to `Elixir.None`.

Comment: Which precisely makes it a module name. There is no practical advantage in making this distinction.

Comment: I disagree. A module name is just an atom. If you wanted, you could do `defmodule :foo do` and that is perfectly valid. In fact, this is precisely how Erlang modules are named because they are just atoms. This is why we call Erlang modules as `:foo.func()` because it is just an atom. All Elixir is doing is making is so that there can be no overlap in module names with Erlang.